# PayPal Mobile SDKS (Adaptive Payments)

Tags: android, ios, mobile, paypal, sdk

Will the new mobile SDK's still require PayPal approval to utilize chained payments when the new rest api is updated with the chained payment functionality (and this support becomes integrated into the mobile sdk's thereafter)?

Edit: How is this access to chained payments permission requested/granted if so?

Answer (score 0):

If chained payments are added to the mSDK, then the approval process to use it will likely just be based on you're ability to use them with the REST APIs. As for the process to use them with REST API, I can't answer how/if that will change from the current approval process until.